# pip install fails from private repository

Tags: python-3.x, pip, nexus3

I have a private pypi repository hosted on Nexus; I am able to upload the package using twine but when I run `pip3 install` it fails

**Upload command:**

`twine upload --repository-url https://nexus.mycompany.com/repository/repos-py-development/ --username ***** --password ***** dist/`

**pip install**

```
pip3 install plugin-sdk --extra-index-url https://nexus.mycompany.com/repository/repos-py-development/
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://nexus.mycompany.com/repository/repos-py-development/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement plugin-sdk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for plugin-sdk
```

- I referred [Cannot collect patch dependency on a local Artifactory Pypi repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945006/cannot-collect-patch-dependency-on-a-local-artifactory-pypi-repository) and found the directory structure is as expected.
- I am able to download the package with simple `curl` command

Answer (score 0):

Adding `simple` to the repository worked.

`pip3 install plugin-sdk --extra-index-url https://nexus.mycompany.com/repository/repos-py-development/simple`